# Select only one radio button in a webform

Tags: forms, webforms

What I need to do is allowing to select only one radio button in a multi-column radios, but each column is in a `<div>`, so they are like in different groups. Here is an example of the code:

```
$form['submitted']['fieldset_time']['time8am'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => array('8:30', '8:45'),
  '#prefix' => '<div style="display:inline-block">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#title' => '8 a.m.',
  '#weight' => 8,
);

$form['submitted']['fieldset_time']['time9am'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => array('9:00','9:15','9:30', '9:45'),
  '#prefix' => '<div style="display:inline-block">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#title' => '9 a.m.',
  '#weight' => 9,
);
```

With this code, the radios are displayed in 2 columns but I can choose two options, what can I do to only allow to choose one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the radios approach is that they're separate form fields, so the browser is correctly allowing only one selection per field.

Instead, you should use radio - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#radio and specify the attribute of name to only allow one value to be selected.

I'm assuming this is going to be built programmatically in a loop instead of procedurally, but I'll demonstrate as if this was hard-coded. Also, in a perfect world you'd add markup in the theme, not in the form definition.

```
$form['submitted']['800_title'] = array(
  '#markup' => '8 a.m.',
  '#prefix' => '<div style="display:inline-block">',
);

$form['submitted']['830'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radio',
  '#value' => 'default',
  '#return_value' => '0830',
  '#title' => t('8:30am'),
  '#attributes' => array('name' => array('time')),
  '#prefix' => '',
  '#suffix' => '',
);

$form['submitted']['845'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radio',
  '#value' => 'default',
  '#return_value' => '0845',
  '#title' => t('8:45am'),
  '#attributes' => array('name' => array('time')),
  '#prefix' => '',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);

$form['submitted']['900_title'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '<div style="display:inline-block">',
  '#markup' => '9 a.m.',
);

$form['submitted']['900'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radio',
  '#value' => 'default',
  '#return_value' => '0900',
  '#title' => t('9:00am'),
  '#attributes' => array('name' => array('time')),
  '#prefix' => '',
  '#suffix' => '',
);

$form['submitted']['915'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radio',
  '#value' => 'default',
  '#return_value' => '0915',
  '#title' => t('9:15am'),
  '#attributes' => array('name' => array('time')),
  '#prefix' => '',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

Comment: The #attributes lines caused issues for me when attempting to access the selection during form_submit. I removed those lines, added a fieldset element to wrap all the radios and added a #parents value array to each radio referencing the key of the fieldset. With this, not only was I able to restrict selection to only one radio, but I also saw that selection in my form_state['values'] on submit.